# JSON invalid token

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

Hello,
I have a very annoying issue with my parse function. I'm receiving a JSON string (I'm most certain it is) from my websocket server. I have validated it online but still get a "invalid token" error when parsing it with my script.

However, if I put in into the function manually everything works perfect. What's wrong with my string?

```
function parseSocketMsg(msg){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
        $.each(obj, function(i, item){
            var rec = getRect(item.id);
            rec.x = item.x;
            rec.y = item.y;
        });
}

function connect(){
    var host = "ws://localhost:8080/scrabble/server.php";
    try{
        socket = new WebSocket(host);
        print("Connected. Awaiting Handshake...");
        socket.onopen    = function(msg){
            if(!ctx){
                init();
            } 
            print("Connection established - status "+this.readyState); 
        };
        socket.onmessage = function(msg){ parseSocketMsg(msg.data); };
        socket.onclose   = function(msg){ print("Connection Lost! Reconnecting..."); connect(); };
    }
    catch(ex){}
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example JSON string?

Comment: Try logging the input for yourself, either by using firebug's console.log or a simple alert.

Comment: This is the one received: [{"id":7,"x":637,"y":151},{"id":23,"x":672,"y":151},{"id":10,"x":733,"y":416}]

Comment: @Nokus: If you are using Chrome, there is a great resource to see actual received data: chrome://net-internals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar question recently, the problem was that there was an unexpect null character at beginning and end of the string.

I recommend that you dump in hex the exact contents of what your are trying to parse, visual inspection doesn't always show up weirdness in character data.

Comment: ymmd, there was an additional character at the beginning which screwed everything up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have `var host = "ws://...` could this be the problem? Are you sure you receive anything? (log/print/whatever whatever you get). I suppose you are reading the logs in the server and assuming that your js is getting it.

Comment: I had it printed on the browser, copied it back directly into the js only to find out it differs from the one I receive. It also worked 0.o